# How to make polling observable detect unfullfilled promise

Tags: rxjs, polling

This observable polls `getPromise()` function every second. After `getPromise()` function returns 3 promises it stops resolving them. How do I detect that `getPromise()` function hasn't resolve/rejected any promise for the past, let's say, 2 seconds, and call `onError` handler. I've tried making it work with `timeout` operator to no avail. Any ideas?

```js
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getPromise()))
  .subscribe(onValue, onError);

function onValue(value){
  console.log('value: ', value);
}
function onError(error){
  console.log('error: ', error);
}
var getPromise = (function(){
  var counter = 3;
  return function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if(counter > 0) resolve(1);
      counter--;
    })
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.3.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`race`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-race) operator that subscribes only to the first Observable that emits.

You said you want to call `onError` handler after 2 of inactivity. This contradicts with using `switchMap` which automatically unsubscribes when a new Observable is returned from its callback. So you might want to use [`exhaustMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-exhaustMap) instead. Also when you emit an error notification the chain unsubscribes and you'll never receive any other value. This means that you shouldn't emit the timeout as an `error` or use also the [`retry`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) operator to automatically resubscribe (but this really depends on what you're trying to achieve).

This is you updated example that is just using the `race()` operator.

```js
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .switchMap(() => 
    Rx.Observable.race(
      Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getPromise()),
      Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).mapTo(42)
    )
  )
  .subscribe(onValue, onError);

function onValue(value){
  console.log('value: ', value);
}
function onError(error){
  console.log('error: ', error);
}
var getPromise = (function(){
  var counter = 3;
  return function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if(counter > 0) resolve(1);
      counter--;
    })
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.3.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

Edit: To send a single error notification after 2 seconds of inactivity.

```js
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .switchMap(() => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getPromise()))
  .timeout(2000)
  .subscribe(onValue, onError);

function onValue(value){
  console.log('value: ', value);
}
function onError(error){
  console.log('error: ', error);
}
var getPromise = (function(){
  var counter = 3;
  return function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if(counter > 0) resolve(1);
      counter--;
    })
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.2.0/Rx.js"></script>
```

There's really a bug in 5.3.0 not directly in the `timeout()` operator but in scheduling async actions. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2580

Without the `timeout()` operator:

```
Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
  .switchMap(() =>
    Rx.Observable.race(
      Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getPromise()),
      Rx.Observable.timer(0, 2000).map(function(_) {
        throw new Error('timeout');
      })
    )
  )
  .subscribe(onValue, onError);
```

Comment: Hey, that's a great solution! How would you unsubscribe after you get the first 42? I don't need the rest of them.

Comment: this observable is supposed to unsuscribe after 2s has passed and no value was emitted.

Comment: @EugeneEpifanov See my update that uses `timeout()` to throw the error. It actually looks like there's a bug in RxJS 5.3.0 in the `timeout()` operator. With RxJS 5.2.0 it works as should I guess. There have been changes to the `timeout()` operator recently however https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#530-2017-04-03

Comment: I added also a variant without the `timeout()` operator.

Comment: RxJS 5 already has a PR to fix this issue https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/pull/2580